# Probability tricky exercise (Poisson)

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I've been trying to solve this exercise about Poisson but it seems my reasoning is not correct.

It goes like this:

> Failures in a system are modeled according to a Poisson process with a rate of $0.015$ failures/hour. Every time a fault occurs, the system stops to be repair
>   Since repairs are expensive, and requires 10 hours for each failure, it is of great interest to estimate by simulation the proportion of the system's inoperable time (that is, the ratio of total repair time to total active operating time).
>
> 1) Simulate $5$ times between failures from the following random values: $0.944$, $0.5253$, $0.6571$, $0.951$, $0.3383$.
>   Write the $5$ simulated values separated by a space.
>   Note: in a Poisson process the times between events are exponentially distributed.
>
> 2) From the $5$ simulated values from point 1), calculate the proportion of time that the system was not operable.
>
> 3) We now want to simulate $10$ non-operable time ratio values. For this, we will repeat the previous steps $9$ more times, using the following random numbers:
>
> ```
>  0.944     0.5253    0.6571    0.951     0.3383    
>  0.2735    0.7894    0.3067    0.7617    0.9497    
>  0.5512    0.5871    0.4472    0.0338    0.8519    
>  0.0793    0.6877    0.8679    0.2803    0.6606    
>  0.9513    0.7587    0.8264    0.4401    0.065     
>  0.1108    0.3068    0.2353    0.1592    0.3166    
>  0.3171    0.0158    0.9257    0.9631    0.8393    
>  0.1995    0.8858    0.1165    0.3954    0.3075    
>  0.6685    0.8801    0.6398    0.7918    0.309     
>  0.1345    0.5291    0.3983    0.633     0.9775
> ```
>
> Use each row of $5$ values to generate a simulated non-operable time ratio value. Answer the $10$ simulated total values separated by spaces.
>   Note: the first row is the one given in the first item, so the first value of the answer has already been calculated.
>
> 4) Calculate the average value among the $10$ simulated values from point 3) for the proportion of non-operable time.

This is my reasoning:

0.015 failures per hour **means** that on average there is 1/0.015 = **66.66 hours** between failures, right? The five random numbers give the times between successive failures (random number x 66.66)

So, in order to solve point 1) i would need to do this:

```
0.944 * 66.66 = 62.93
0.5253 * 66.66 = 35.02 
0.6571 * 66.66 = 43.81
0.951 * 66.66 = 63.40 
0.3383 * 66.66 = 22.55
```

The answer for point 1) would be:

```
62.93 . . . 35.02 . . . 43.81 . . . 63.40 . . . 22.55
```

---

Next, point 2). It says: **"the proportion of time that the system was not operable"**

Then, the operating time is the sum of 62.93 + 35.02 + 43.81 + 63.40 + 22.55 = 227.71.

```
Operating time = 227.71 hours
```

The downtime is **5 periods** of **10 hours** = 50 hours.

and this is a proportion of 50/227.1 = 21.95%

Hence non-operating time = **21.95%** (not sure of this one)

> **Mental note:** If I were operating this system, I would be more interested in the proportion of wasted time over the entire available
>   time (not simply repair time over operating time), which means that
>   the percentage should be 50/(227.71 + 50) = 18.00% So if 21.95% is not
>   an acceptable answer, then it is possible that the required answer may
>   be 18.00%.. Again, not sure about it.

---

Next, point 3)

What am i supposed to do here? Just do the same for the other 9 sets of random numbers? Find the average of the ten percentages? Don't get it. :/

---

Finally, point 4)

I do not understand this one, i'm a little confused.

---

Could you please tell me if my answers for point 1 and 2 are correct?

How would you solve points 3) and 4)?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

So, i would need to do this in point 1):

```
[-log(1-0.944)]/[(0.015)] --> 192.160
[-log(1-0.5253)]/[(0.015)] --> 49.6715
[-log(1-0.6571)]/[(0.015)] --> 71.3544
[-log(1-0.951)]/[(0.015)] --> 201.062
[-log(1-0.3383)]/[(0.015)] --> 27.529
```

Answer shoud be:

> 192.160|49.6715|71.3544|201.062|27.529

---

For point 2) i would need to do this:

```
[-log(1-0.944)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.5253)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.6571)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.951)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.3383)]/[(0.015)]
```

I mean:

```
0.944     0.5253    0.6571    0.951     0.3383  -->  541.7769
```

It would give me this number: **541.7769**

Then, i should do this calculation:

```
50/(541.7769 + 50) =  0.08449
```

---

For point 3)

```
[-log(1-0.944)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.5253)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.6571)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.951)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.3383)]/[(0.015)]  
[-log(1-0.2735)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.7894)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.3067)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.7617)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.9497)]/[(0.015)]    
[-log(1-0.5512)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.5871)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.4472)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.0338)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.8519)]/[(0.015)]    
[-log(1-0.0793)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.6877)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.8679)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.2803)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.6606)]/[(0.015)]    
[-log(1-0.9513)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.7587)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.8264)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.4401)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.0650)]/[(0.015)]     
[-log(1-0.1108)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.3068)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.2353)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.01592)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.3166)]/[(0.015)]    
[-log(1-0.3171)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.0158)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.9257)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.9631)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.8393)]/[(0.015)]    
[-log(1-0.1995)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.8858)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.1165)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.3954)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.3075)]/[(0.015)]    
[-log(1-0.6685)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.8801)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.6398)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.7918)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.3090)]/[(0.015)]     
[-log(1-0.1345)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.5291)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.3983)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.6330)]/[(0.015)]+[-log(1-0.9775)]/[(0.015)]
```

So, after performing the calculations (using wolfram) i got this results:

```
0.944     0.5253    0.6571    0.951     0.3383  -->  541.778
0.2735    0.7894    0.3067    0.7617    0.9497  -->  444.505
0.5512    0.5871    0.4472    0.0338    0.8519  -->  281.516
0.0793    0.6877    0.8679    0.2803    0.6606  -->  312.007
0.9513    0.7587    0.8264    0.4401    0.065   -->  456.133
0.1108    0.3068    0.2353    0.01592    0.3166  --> 76.5910
0.3171    0.0158    0.9257    0.9631    0.8393  -->  541.649
0.1995    0.8858    0.1165    0.3954    0.3075  -->  225.788
0.6685    0.8801    0.6398    0.7918    0.309   -->  412.346
0.1345    0.5291    0.3983    0.633     0.9775  -->  413.479
```

Anwers for point 3) should be:

```
541.778|444.505|281.516|312.007|456.133|76.5910|541.649|225.788|412.346|413.479
```

---

I'm not sure about point 4) :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have the right interpretation of part $1$.  The cumulative distribution function of the exponential distribution is $$F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x},\ x\geq0$$ and when you're given a random number $r$, I think you are supposed to find $x$ such that $F(x)=r$, that is $$x=\frac{-\log(1-r)}\lambda.$$  This is the usual way of simulating distributions other than the uniform distribution.

For part $2$, I'm sure your second thought is right.  You should be looking at the total time.

For part $3$ yes, just do it $10$ more times.  This gives you $10$ averages.

For part $4$ it says to take the average of the $10$ averages computed in part $3$.  This is a bit odd, It seems like the right thing to do is to compute total downtime over total time, but that's not what the exercise says.they will all cover different lengths of time.

Comment: Hey dude, thank you very much for replying!.
I'm sorry, i do not fully understand your explanation for point 1). How would you solve that for this particular case?

Comment: In this case, $\lambda=.015$

Comment: So in the first case, where $r=.944$ the time to failure would be $-\log(1-.944)/.015\approx192.16$

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense but i got this question rolling in my mind, pal: why what i did in point 1) was not correct? What would it be the right explanation for that?

Comment: If the average time to failure is $66$ hours, but you always compute a time to failure less than $66$ hours, then the average time to failure must really be less than $66$ hours, so your interpretation can't be right.  On the other hand, the only way I know what the question is really asking for is from prior experience.

Comment: What the $.994$ means is that $99.4\%$ of all failures will occur within this time.

Comment: Yeah, what you write seems correct and makes sense.. i'm sorry, this is my first time using "Poisson" everything seems a little complicated but i will improve :). I'm checking point 3) and 4).. stay sharp!

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark, so that others see it has been resolved.

Comment: Dude, take a look: i have updated my question

Comment: You seem to be off by a factor of $10$.  $\lambda=.015$ you say, but your calculations use $.15$  How could the average time to breakdown be $66$ hours and $99.4\%$ of all breakdowns come within $19.2$ hours?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake :/. Take a look, i've edited my question. Not sure about point 4) :/

Comment: Hey dude, how are you? I'm still struggling / trying to understand point 4). You told me to *compute total downtime over total time* but not really sure about that. How would you do that?. I thought the point 4 was asking me to do the same like i did in point 2). Am i wrong?

Comment: No, that isn't what I said.  I said that that would appear to me to be the logical thing to do, but it is not what the question says to do.  It says do the same thing you did in part $2)$ for each line, so you get $10$ values, and then to take the average of those $10$ values.

Comment: Two things:
a)you mean i should do this?: 541.778+444.505+281.516+312.007+456.133+76.5910+541.649+225.788+412.346+413.479--->3705.792 and then, use that value and perform this operation: [50]/[3705.792+50]?
b)How would you compute the total downtime over total time?

Comment: I don't know what these numbers are.  If the answers for part 3) you should take their average: add them up and divide by $10$.  Part b) has nothing to do with this exercise.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, pal :)

Comment: Dude, i need a tutor. Are you willing to help me to practice for my exam? 02:00 hs?

Comment: No, this is not a tutoring site.

Comment: Hey dude, could you please check this exercise? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700206/poisson-exercise-mixed

Comment: If you have another question, post another question.  And stop calling me dude.